# Metric space problem.

Tags: metric-spaces

Suppose $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $z$ belongs to $\mathbb{R}$. Then prove that 
dist $(z, S) \leq |z-\sup S|$ with equality if $z\geq \sup S$. 
I can easily prove it for $S=\varnothing$. But how to prove it in another case.

Comment: What is $\varphi$? Is the distance between $z$ and $S$ defined as the infimum of the distances between $z$ and $s$ over all $s \in S$?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee I think that is $\emptyset$.

Comment: @SuzuHirose Okay, I'll edit so that it reads that.

Answer (score 2):

Take a sequence $x_k\in S$ such that $x_k \to \sup S$. Then $d(z,S) \le |z-x_k| \to |z-\sup S|$.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that

$$d(z,S) = \inf\{|z-x| : x\in S\}.$$

So by definition, $d(z,S)\le |z-x|$ for any $x\in S$. Let $s=\sup S$ and let $\varepsilon > 0$. By the definition of supremum, there exists $y\in S$ with $s-y<\varepsilon$. Hence

$$ d(z,S) \leqslant |z-y| \leqslant |z-s|+|s-y| < |z-s| + \varepsilon, $$

so that $d(z,S)\leqslant |z-s|$. If additionally $z\geqslant s$, then $|z-s|\leqslant |z-x|$ for any $x\in S$ (since $s\geqslant x$), which implies that $|z-s|\leqslant d(z,S)$.